# Error while parsing the URDF file

Tags: urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

while making URDF file,when i am going to run `./bin/parser my_robot.urdf` i got following error:

```
[ERROR] [1379365363.499555623]: Could not open file [my_robot.urdf] for parsing.
[ERROR] [1379365363.499662656]: Failed to parse urdf file
```

plz tell me how to solve it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/79711/error-while-parsing-the-urdf-file/) by [pavanpatel](https://answers.ros.org/users/5686/pavanpatel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2013-09-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-09-16**:
Please, explain more detailed your problem in the description, not in the title of your question.

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-09-16**:
What distro of ROS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a dot missing in the second tutorial.

From your workspace, run:  ~/catkin_ws$ ./devel/lib/testbot_description/parser ./src/testbot_description/urdf/my_robot.urdf

It worked for me.

---

Originally posted by [jaimerv](https://answers.ros.org/users/11726/jaimerv/) with karma: 96 on 2014-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

test this one in the path of the urdf file ( :~/catkin_ws/src/testbot_description/urdf$)
~/catkin_ws/devel/lib/testbot_description/parser  ~/catkin_ws/src/testbot_description/urdf/my_robot.urdf)

---

Originally posted by [Zargol](https://answers.ros.org/users/6711/zargol/) with karma: 206 on 2013-09-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1